# Como contar quantidade de checkbox selecionados

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Eu estou tentando fazer um código que verifica quantos checkbox estão marcados ao clicar em um botão, pois estou fazendo um sistema que duplica registros. Tenho uma lista com vários checkbox, e quando a pessoa clicar no botão "duplicar" o jQuery vai verificar quais estão marcados e pegar o **value** deles. Não tenho ideia de como fazer, pois tentei de várias formas e nada. O último código que tentei foi esse:

```
<script>
(document).ready(function(){

    $("#duplicar-registro").on('click', function(){

        var checkbox = $("#mcheckbox");

        for(i=0;i<= checkbox.length;i++){

            if($("input[id=mcheckbox]:checked") == true){

                console.log(i); //Ver no console
            }else{

                console.log(i); //Ver no console também
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para pegar os valores dos `checkbox` selecionados, primeiramente você deverá alterar o seletor de sua função. Não é permitido mais de um elemento com o mesmo `id`, então sugiro utilizar o nome do `checkbox` ou um classe para isto, segue exemplo de sugestão de implementação:

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="mcheckbox[]" /> 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="mcheckbox[]" /> 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="mcheckbox[]" /> 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="mcheckbox[]" /> 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="mcheckbox[]" /> 5</label>
<button type="button" id="duplicar-registro">Duplicar Registro</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('#duplicar-registro').click(function () {
    //seletor para os checkbox com name mcheckbox selecionados
    var checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name^=mcheckbox]:checked');
    //verifica se existem checkbox selecionados
    if(checkbox.length > 0){
        //array para armazenar os valores
        var val = [];
        //função each para pegar os selecionados
        checkbox.each(function(){
            val.push($(this).val());
        });
        //exibe no console o array com os valores selecionados
        console.log(val);
    } 
});
```

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/UtL36/1/)**

Comment: Acredito que o exemplo não esteja funcionando!

Comment: @GabrielBorghi acredito que devido atualização do JSFiddle o jQuery não esta sendo incluido, veja aqui http://jsfiddle.net/UtL36/31/

Comment: É pra mim não funciona, mas beleza era só pra ter certeza caso alguém precise, mas o código ja me ajudou valeu.

Answer (score 6):

***Exemplo:*** [**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Kymrx/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CheckBox Selecionados</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check1" id="check1">1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check2" id="check2">2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check3" id="check3">3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="check4" id="check4">4<br>
    <input type="button" value="Verificar" id="btnverificar" name="btnverificar">    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#btnverificar").click(function(e) {
                $.each(($("input[type=checkbox]:checked")), function(index, obj){
                    console.log(obj.value);
                });
            });         
        });
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```